# Internal Error 500 when called from Open Social Gadget - IBM Connections

Tags: ibm-connections, opensocial

I am getting an Internal Error ( We are unable to process your request ) when I try to call a Portal Service from IBM Connections Openocial gadget. I have tried the url using a Firefox Rest Client, which posts and works properly

We have an SSO setup at the WAS Level, through export/import of LTPA Tokens, which is working fine.

The below piece if code runs from an EE through an Activity Stream.

Requesting help in identifying the issue

> ```
>           var url = "http://portaldomain:20014/wps/myportal";
>             var params = {};
>             var headers = {};
>             params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.METHOD] = gadgets.io.MethodType.POST;
>             params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.CONTENT_TYPE] = gadgets.io.ContentType.TEXT;
>             params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.AUTHORIZATION] = gadgets.io.AuthorizationType.SIGNED;
>             postdata = gadgets.io.encodeValues(postdata);
>             params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.POST_DATA]= postdata;
>             gadgets.io.makeRequest(url, response, params);
> ```

```
Following are the set of parameters that I see through firebug

authz   signed
bypassSpecCache 0
container   default
contentType TEXT
gadget  https://connectionsdomain/gadgets/EEWCMApproveGadget.xml
getFullHeaders  false
getSummaries    false
httpMethod  POST
numEntries  3
oauthState  
postData    uuid=d39110f1-dbe7-4731-82e1-fda4654ac366&status=approve&comment=Approved
signOwner   true
signViewer  true
st  default:0zKcYH7ZZK_19x4m3ifbVRCg1E7qUZm54EWcZzjGuiadgfrpM57pgi4fLik56unzOQ0Vq0HfGAwq9-_ZgOBOIGE_x6laCP6yhavqa3yY0EQRvGVLxh0qr6rch3XUyrGwi9ClUb9tFmDO3NdJGRB2QCT2T3ZMwX3lrYaBypirH7b3tJZ8Da_HPxKm4JziWHk4g-WF4I-y1rGYwiDdl24S88iVyMJnX1jao2aBzwlO_yQ
url http://portaldomain:20014/wps/mycontenthandler/wcmrest/item/d39110f1-dbe7-4731-82e1-fda4654ac366/approve
```

```html
[1/14/15 11:26:10:024 IST] 0000008f servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [WidgetContainer] [/connections/opensocial] [makeRequest]: Initialization successful.
[1/14/15 11:26:10:055 IST] 0000008f servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: An exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet [makeRequest] in application [WidgetContainer]. Exception created : [java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.shindig.gadgets.oauth.OAuthRequest.fetch(OAuthRequest.java:179)
 at org.apache.shindig.gadgets.http.DefaultRequestPipeline.fetchResponse(DefaultRequestPipeline.java:168)
 at org.apache.shindig.gadgets.http.DefaultRequestPipeline.execute(DefaultRequestPipeline.java:108)
 at org.apache.shindig.gadgets.servlet.MakeRequestHandler.fetch(MakeRequestHandler.java:217)
 at org.apache.shindig.gadgets.servlet.AsyncMakeRequestServlet.serverMakeRequestFile(AsyncMakeRequestServlet.java:143)
 at org.apache.shindig.gadgets.servlet.AsyncMakeRequestServlet.doGet(AsyncMakeRequestServlet.java:135)
 at org.apache.shindig.gadgets.servlet.AsyncMakeRequestServlet.doPost(AsyncMakeRequestServlet.java:167)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
 at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307)
 at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:562)
 at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:255)
 at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
 at com.ibm.cre.server.auth.AuthenticationServletFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationServletFilter.java:42)





***Trace Logs*****


[1/14/15 11:26:02:677 IST] 0000008f CookieBasedSS 1   cookieNames = LtpaToken,LtpaToken2,PD-H-SESSION-ID,PD-S-SESSION-ID,SMIDENTITY,SMSESSION
[1/14/15 11:26:02:677 IST] 0000008f CookieBasedSS 1   cookieDomain = .poc.com
[1/14/15 11:26:02:677 IST] 0000008f CookieBasedSS 3   adding cookie LtpaToken=ftZFybOO0OjWSwVYdwCbCnVLvYxk5w+jqlrebGIxfAvwL68Ud9rOa/Ogla3YHJKA8W3s0ZgO6r6yBZHf6DKRjToQs2weu9/xSbKi9coM/2chEcbF/vAX6YauO8Er1dnXEFnFLvUKvpEy5KE1+BLPID6RyYgoaQ/sQcpQiMBg6oDYuRDdm01p4CIh/0wjCbICNrWpetNo8PxKxk9yaaemSQ4gInquZ162CWDGyHVpS+LaxF9ohQxPkYUC0wZDK1VExECCMVdhivW9FfE/1TZQjrhSdDRDN1VRj9bvcfWc2h7/H2iwdtrXBQ==;LtpaToken2=xGSl1AuYtM0f2GRbiqtBuK0r5G+VCv8MaWLmsQAMSi6mNMVpUQozaPWYdSdgEd60Sez++e2mXrGnhLK0wMU1glbbx81XaWZzka1fCIo1VsJHSMlphEc/qv1AlhFRvA1ThesjY5JKaxLcQD7mcWif3HugM5iZeP/lKjWoRLUku+6wYTXI7urSgU2aELq+1QtoiFbiAubfk4f2e/zUUXgZ+LcAjiBgae9abEV5yFPoQmKorodGQ4QMif7eYJNQuqzdSoeIJc2flCgFjLMb7uZ/JN48UUG21poROqCjEc21oxmqQmnCZNyCJ1xpyG3p1OPGX2AL/cjnIOhGPaw6itarreB0dBJNPaT6eqVDjscfVwbTQJ/mHR840TG9C52QvDzW9mHwM74jwUBojZwCneew+g1Si2O9j55debqGvvUl0RNHoEUjIWsB2lhiQ/SH9d2XnMKV6H03rLIctip/cQ5hu/nghTctw+iOVe+Aa7+uUAA2elVMFCNetpHNKaPh4KhPBGsXdkK8aDFpqhhIyoeSBPIiz2dXs5Uaf67ZgZJ4eoTdw7JxBPliV6n3UVD2r0JcE4qSW0VxTK8qeszhhqKsflEfcuozJVr7T2fSusiEd1+BAo8iIU1nmGJFB+aJcoEZS4cQC+8ghtUXGsPdZLnGLII9rQcVa6LwxrllZCQIW3M=
[1/14/15 11:26:02:677 IST] 0000008f GadgetRenderi 3   headers extracted, Cookie :[LtpaToken=ftZFybOO0OjWSwVYdwCbCnVLvYxk5w+jqlrebGIxfAvwL68Ud9rOa/Ogla3YHJKA8W3s0ZgO6r6yBZHf6DKRjToQs2weu9/xSbKi9coM/2chEcbF/vAX6YauO8Er1dnXEFnFLvUKvpEy5KE1+BLPID6RyYgoaQ/sQcpQiMBg6oDYuRDdm01p4CIh/0wjCbICNrWpetNo8PxKxk9yaaemSQ4gInquZ162CWDGyHVpS+LaxF9ohQxPkYUC0wZDK1VExECCMVdhivW9FfE/1TZQjrhSdDRDN1VRj9bvcfWc2h7/H2iwdtrXBQ==;LtpaToken2=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]
[1/14/15 11:26:02:677 IST] 0000008f GadgetRenderi 3   headers extracted, Authorization :null
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure per gadget policy rules 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYGQH_5.0.0/admin/admin/t_admin_common_cre11_conn_security_proxy.dita

The file should be in /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/{profile}/config/cells/{cell}/LotusConnections-config/opensocial-proxy-rules

You should find proxy-policy.dynamic it's a well documented file, and you can edit it 
add a rule such as 
`allow(".*", "http:\\/\\/www\\.ibm\\.com\\/gadgets\\/gadget.xml", ""http\\:\\/\\/www\\.ibm\\.com\\/.*");`

Comment: I added the code as suggested, but still I receive the same error. I am also attaching the logs information in my question

Comment: Is that "headers extracted, Authorization :null" the issue. How can this be resolved ? This is what I have added in the proxy-policy file:  allow("*", "*", "*");

Comment: you want to add .* under allow otherwise you are matching the empty string

Comment: Its in deed * in both the places, but somehow did not reflect in the comment

Comment: I suggest you open a PMR in this case.

Comment: Sure will do that, Any other suggestions, readings that I can try. I was following the wiki article and was trying to create something on those lines http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Redbooks%3A+Building+and+Implementing+Social+Digital+Experiences#action=openDocument&res_title=10.3_Action_a_Workflow_Action_Request_via_an_Embedded_Experience_Open_Social_Gadget&content=pdcontent